# Wrap unwrapped text in <span>

Tags: php, regex

Example:

```
<div>foo</div>
<p>bar</p>
Unwrapped text
```

What i want:

```
<div>foo</div>
<p>bar</p>
<span>Unwrapped text</span>
```

How to achieve this **without** relying on new lines?

Comment: First you must define what you mean with "wrap" text. Because all the code should be wrapped, at least, with <html> tags. Second, what do you mean without relying on new lines? Third and last, why is this tagged under php/regex? If you actually want some php code, can you show us what you have tried already please?

Comment: The usual comment for people who want to parse html using regular expressions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Curios what happens for `<div><p>Text</p>More text</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use regular expressions for html.

You can do it with [phpQuery](https://github.com/punkave/phpQuery)

```
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($html);
$doc->contents()->not($doc->children())->wrap("<span>");
$html = $doc->html();
```

Didn't try it though.

Answer (score 1):

Extract tokens from your string like for example: `<div>`, `foo`, `</div>`, `<p>`, `bar`, `</p>`, `Unwrapped text`. You can do this with regular expressions. Then

```
for each token do
    if token is opening tag
        push token on stack
    else if token is closing tag (and matching opening tag is ontop of stack)
        pop token from stack
    else if token is text and stack is not empty
        ignore token (continue)
    else if token is text and stack is empty
        wrap token with <span>
```

This will work for arbitrary nested `XML`-strings.